# ¿Como puedo generar un Drop-down para Excel desde C# con la librería ClosedXml?

Tags: c#

Verán estoy generado un archivo de Excel con información obtenida desde la DB. Mi problema es que no puedo lograr que en cierta columna se agregue un dropdown para cada registro.

A continuación les muestro lo que tengo.

```
var countRow = 1;
                XLWorkbook workbook = new XLWorkbook();

                var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Incidencias");

                worksheet.Cells("A1").Value = "Clave de Trabajador";
                worksheet.Cells("B1").Value = "Nombre";
                worksheet.Cells("C1").Value = "Perfil de Turno";
                worksheet.Cells("D1").Value = "Fecha";
                worksheet.Cells("E1").Value = "Entrada_Turno";
                worksheet.Cells("F1").Value = "Entrada_Salida";
                worksheet.Cells("G1").Value = "Monto";
                worksheet.Cells("H1").Value = "Movimiento";
                worksheet.Cells("I1").Value = "Supervisor";
                worksheet.Cells("J1").Value = "Incidencias";

                string[] options = {
                    "Falta", 
                    "Días Permiso Sin Goce de Sueldo", 
                    "Días Permiso Con Goce de Sueldo", 
                    "Castigo", 
                    "Retardo",
                    "Hrs Permiso Sin Goce de Sueldo", 
                    "Hrs Permiso Con Goce de Sueldo", 
                    "Tiempo Extra", 
                };

                var comboCell = worksheet.Cell("J2");

                foreach (var item in dataIncidentsList)
                {
                    countRow++;
                    worksheet.Cells("A" + countRow).Value = item.WorkerKey;
                    worksheet.Cells("B" + countRow).Value = item.Name;
                    worksheet.Cells("C" + countRow).Value = item.ShiftProfileName;
                    worksheet.Cells("D" + countRow).Value = item.Date;
                    worksheet.Cells("E" + countRow).Value = item.EntryShift;
                    worksheet.Cells("F" + countRow).Value = item.EntryExit;
                    worksheet.Cells("G" + countRow).Value = Convert.ToDouble(item.Value);
                    worksheet.Cell("G" + countRow).Style.NumberFormat.Format = "0.0";
                    worksheet.Cells("H" + countRow).Value = item.IncidentName;
                    worksheet.Cells("I" + countRow).Value = item.Supervisor;

                    var dataValidation = worksheet.Range("J2:J" + (options.Length + 1)).SetDataValidation();
                    dataValidation.List(comboCell.Value.ToString(), true);

                    foreach (var option in options)
                    {
                        comboCell.CellBelow().SetValue(option);
                        comboCell = comboCell.CellBelow();
                    }
                }
```

Necesito que la columna J contenga los dropdown con la información del arreglo de string.

Estoy usando la librería ClosedXml. Agradezco todo aporte.